# Как скомпилировать программу на GO

Tags: golang, компиляция

Подскажите кто нибудь. Вот скачал и установил язык Go. Как теперь скомпилировать и запустить программу?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ go build fileName.go
```

Comment: А можно поподробнее. Когда открою командную строку что прописывать. Если прописывать go build fileName.go. Пишет go не является внутренней или внешней командой.

Comment: Значит у вас путь к файлу go не прописан. Вот почитайте http://golang.org/doc/install

Comment: Спасибо с этим разобрался. Теперь пишет imports unicode: C:\Go\src\pkg\fmt\format.go:10:2: C:\Go\src\pkg\unicode: found packages unicode (casetables.go) and main (maketables.go)

Answer (score 3):

Убедись что компилятор есть в PATH 
Eсли есть то в папке с исходниками shif + пкм > открыть окно PowerShell здесь (или командную строку) > пишешь go build ./filename.go 
вроде так 
так же может помочь эта [статья](https://medium.com/golang-notes/%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-visual-studio-code-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-go-647ea94aa795)

Answer (score 1):

Запустить в среде Windows можно `go run myProgram.go` где ваша программа myProgram.go или `C:\Go\bin\go.exe run D:/go/myProgram.go` . 
Скомпилировать и запустить можно с помощю команды go build - `go build D:/go/myProgram.go`

Answer (score 0):

Компилируется все именно так:
go build fileName.go

Если вам нужно скомпилировать под все системы и если вы в linux, то я буквально сейчас написал на bash скрипт для компиляции под все OS.

```
cu=`pwd`
rm -rf release/packages && echo "success deletion" || echo "not success"
mkdir -p release/packages/
os_all='linux windows darwin freebsd'
arch_all='386 amd64 arm arm64 mips64 mips64le mips mipsle'
for os in $os_all; do
    for arch in $arch_all; do
      set GOOS=$os
      set GOARCH=$arch
      if [ $os = "windows" ]; then
        go build -o $os"_"$arch".exe" && echo "Success build for arch "$arch" and os "$os || echo "No problem"
        mv $os"_"$arch".exe" release/packages && echo "Move success" || echo "Move not success"
      else
        go build -o $os"_"$arch && echo "Success build for arch "$arch" and os "$os || echo "No problem"
        mv $os"_"$arch release/packages && echo "Move success" || echo "Move not success"
      fi
    done
done
echo "Success Build"
cd $cu
```

Просто создайте новый файл compile.sh, положите туда этот код и зайдите в терминал. С помощью cd перейдите в эту папку и напишите bash compile.sh

После этого ваш скрипт на Go будет скомпилирован под все системы. Найти готовые файлы можно будет в папке release/packages.